# Change initial route after Validation - react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm struggling to find a solution to my problem, but no success yet.

My idea is: when the user receives the 6 digits code from the API and hits `confirm` the page will reload and send him to the main app. I have looked around if there is any function that can help me resolve my problem, but the only idea that seems to be working for now is to link the button from the `ValidationPage` to the rooting stack and give the function `onPress` to send the user to the MainPage.js.

But my opinion is that this is not the right way to do this. So does anyone have an idea how to tackle this problem? I'll be glad if someone can help me. Thank you! The outlook of the page looks like this :

**LoginPage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Linking, Image, View, AsyncStorage, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Container, Icon, Text, Content, Button, Input, Item } from "native-base";

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    state = {
        fontLoaded: false,
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
            Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
            Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
        });

        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    }

    render() {



        return (
            this.state.fontLoaded ? (
                <Container>
                    <Content>
                        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: '60%',
                                    height: 200,
                                }}
                                source={require('../../assets/images/Shootlog.png')} />

                        </View>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, color: 'grey' }}> Welcome to myShootLog</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: '#be0202' }}>Smart Shooting Solution for shooting ranges.</Text>
                        <Text style={{ padding: 20, textAlign: 'center', color: 'grey' }}> To continue , please fill in your email adress :</Text>


                        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', margin: 20 }}>

                            <Item style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                                <Input 
                                    placeholder='example@mail.com' 
                                    onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text)} 
                                    value={this.state.email} 
                                    keyboardType='email-address'
                                />
                                <Icon name={this.state.emailCheck} />
                            </Item>
                            <Button full onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Validation')} style={{ backgroundColor: '#e72a2e'}}>

                                <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase', }}>{'send'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                                <Icon name='arrow-forward' />

                            </Button>


                        </View>

                    </Content>
                    <View style={{ width: '100%', alignContent: 'center', position: 'absolute', top: footerTopPosition }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center' }} >All Rights Reserved.® 2018 by CanDoIt </Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center' }} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://candoit.be')}>www.candoit.be</Text>
                    </View>
                </Container>
            ) : null
        );

    }
    validate = (text) => {

        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (reg.test(text) === false) {
            console.log('email is incorrect')
            this.setState({ emailCheck: 'close-circle' });

            return false;

        }
        else {
            this.setState({ emailCheck: 'checkmark-circle' })
            console.log('email is correct')
        }
    }
}
```

**ValidationPage.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Linking, Image, View, AsyncStorage, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { Container, Icon, Text, Content, Button, Input, Item } from "native-base";

export default class ValidationScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {}
    }

    state = {
        fontLoaded: false,
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
            Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
            Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons/fonts/Ionicons.ttf"),
        });

        this.setState({ fontLoaded: true });
    }

    render() {

        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

        return (
            this.state.fontLoaded ? (
                <Container>
                    <Content>
                        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <Image
                                style={{
                                    width: '60%',
                                    height: 200,
                                }}
                                source={require('../../assets/images/Shootlog.png')} />

                        </View>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', lineHeight: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 20, color: 'grey' }}> Welcome to NicoLog</Text>
                        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: '#be0202' }}>Smart Shooting Solution for shooting ranges.</Text>
                        <Text style={{ padding: 20, textAlign: 'center', color: 'grey' }}> Please fill in the 6 digits code from the email that you have recieved :</Text>


                        <View style={{ alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', margin: 20 }}>

                            <Item style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
                                <Input
                                    placeholder='Ex. 910-519'
                                    onChangeText={(text) => this.validate(text)}
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    keyboardType='number-pad'
                                />
                                <Icon name={this.state.emailCheck} />
                            </Item>

                            <Button full onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Main')} style={{ backgroundColor: '#e72a2e' }}>
                                <Icon name='checkmark-circle' />
                                <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>{'confirm'.toUpperCase()}</Text>

                            </Button>
                            <Text style={{ padding: 20, textAlign: 'center', color: 'grey' }}>If you didn't recieved anything please click the button bellow.</Text>
                            <Button full style={{ backgroundColor: '#e72a2e' }}>
                                <Icon name='refresh' />
                                <Text style={{ textTransform: 'uppercase' }}>{'re-send'.toUpperCase()}</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </View>

                    </Content>
                    <View style={{ width: '100%', alignContent: 'center', position: 'absolute', top: footerTopPosition }}>
                        <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 11, textAlign: 'center' }} >All Rights Reserved.® 2018 by CanDoIt </Text>
                        <Text style={{ color: 'grey', fontSize: 10, textAlign: 'center' }} onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://candoit.be')}>www.candoit.be</Text>
                    </View>
                </Container>
            ) : null
        );

    }
    validate = (text) => {

        let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
        if (reg.test(text) === false) {
            console.log('email is incorrect')
            this.setState({ emailCheck: 'close-circle' });

            return false;

        }
        else {
            this.setState({ emailCheck: 'checkmark-circle' })
            console.log('email is correct')
        }
    }


    callMain = () => {
        this.props.callParent(); // accsessing the function from the parent App.js

    }
}
```

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import ValidationScreen from './screens/ValidationScreen';


export default createAppContainer( createStackNavigator (
    {
        Login: { screen: LoginScreen},
        Validation: { screen: ValidationScreen},

    },
    {
        headerMode: 'none'
    }


));
```

Comment: Please Share Navigation file also.

Comment: and if you are using react-navigation you can use  this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Comment: Yes , i use react-navigation . I have updated my request with the navigation.js